# Question about operations with positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$, $B$ are $n ×n$ positive definite matrices and I be the $n ×n$ identity matrix. Then which of the following are positive definite?

1. $A+B$
2. $ABA $
3. $A^2+I$
4. $AB$

My thoughts: From the given condtion we have that the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ are positive and then I need to find the eigenvalues of given matrices. But how can I find them? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Are you assuming that $A$ and $B$ are symmetric? Some people include that in the definition of "positive definite", others don't.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are talking about real symmetric matrices.

1. Is $x^T(A+B)x>0$ for every nonzero vector $x$?
2. Is $x^T(ABA)x = (Ax)^TB(Ax)>0$ for every nonzero vector $x$? (By the way, if $x\not=0$, is $Ax\not=0$?)
3. Is $x^T(A+I)x>0$ for every nonzero vector $x$?
4. Is $AB$ necessarily symmetric? That is, is $AB$ always equal to $(AB)^T=BA$?

Answer (score 1):

If A and B are positive definite matrices then A + B is always a positive definite matrix. 
Proof: If A is positive definite matrix then there exists a non singular matrix P such that P^TAP= I. Now P^T(A+B)P = I+P^TBP and as P^TBP is congruent to B, so all eigen values of P^TBP are positive, so all eigen values of I+P^TBP are positive which implies that all eigen values of P^T(A+B)P are positive and all eigen values of A+B are positive and hence A+B is positive definite.
Here A^+I, ABA will be positive definite.
You can prove similarly.